# Transmission Grinds only in second gear - Need Assistance

Tags: transmission, cadillac, cts

I have a 2003 Cadillac CTS, 6 cylinder 5 speed. 104,000 miles. 
changing from 1st-2nd gear, After letting out the clutch in 2nd gear it has a grinding sound until I shift to 3rd. And only 2nd gear has the sound.

I just got the car, now this... Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: It grinds all the time in second gear? Whether accelerating, coasting (in gear), or decelerating? It runs clean in the other four gears (excluding reverse)? Also, does it shift easily into all of the gears?

Answer (score 3):

It sound like an issue inside the gear box (transmission).  First thing to get checked is the oil level in the gear box.  It could be a simple case of being low on oil.  Get it checked and maybe get an oil change.  If the noise goes, you then need to find where the oil leaked from and get that fixed.